# Looking for games in environments similar to a pinball table

Tags: game-design, level-design

I'm on a team of students working on a third-person adventure game that takes place inside a pinball machine (like, small scale, on the surface, avoiding pinballs, etc).

One of my responsibilities on the project is to find games that are similar to this concept in appearance and/or gameplay for reference.

So, does anyone know of games (other than pinball) that takes place in a pinball-like environment?  Or, adventure games that take place in small, cramped environments with multiple paths around the world?  Or games in which the player is often bombarded with balls (or other similar unintelligent obstacles)?  Or games that take place on a small scale?

Comment: This probably should be on gaming.SE instead of here.

Comment: Gaming.SE's FAQ says such questions are considered off-topic there. Since I'm asking from a design/development perspective, it seems appropriate here. And, the last time I asked a similar question here, I got a lot of helpful feedback: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/are-there-many-games-involving-the-manipulation-of-water

Comment: I guess this would count as a "game recommendation" topic, and therefore off topic for gaming.se, you're right.

Comment: I've seen one on Nick.com ... I think. Or maybe Nick Arcade?

Comment: There is a reddit for game recommendations. It *may* be r/gamerecommendations.

Answer (score 5):

I can think of a few games that might fit what you're looking for.

**Odama:** An old Gamecube game that plays like an RTS inside a pinball machine

**Marvel Ultimate Alliance 2:**  This might be an appropriate 3rd person example of the "cramped environment" that you're looking for

**Toy Soldiers:**  A recent XBLA game that does a great job of convincingly depicting small scale.

Comment: Odama's not old. :(

Comment: Agreed.  Gamecube isn't old enough for its games to be "old". :)  I forgot about Odama.  That'll be a good one to reference.  Thanks for the suggestions, we'll check them out.

Answer (score 2):

> Or games that take place on a small scale?

Micro Machines

[image: Micro Machines VG (old) - billiard]
[image: Micro Machines VG (new) - kitchen]
[image: Micro Machines VG (new) - billiard]

(never played the new one)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how popular it is now, but before Counter-Strike: Source (and even somewhat after), there used to be loads of what were called "rats" maps. Basically they were maps where the scale and texture of the world was designed to make the player feel like they were a rat in a kitchen or some other environment.

While the gameplay was generally still very Counter-Strike like it may not be what you're looking for, but it may help give you some ideas on general concepts of the player being in a world where every day looking objects are huge.

Comment: I think CS:S has remakes of some of those maps.  I'll make sure my team and I have a series of deathmatches... for Science.

Comment: I know they are in CS:S, I just don't know how easy they are to find these days. I haven't tried in a while to land one of them.

Comment: Also there were several made for the Unreal Tournament series (at least, I've played 2004 but some maps said they were remakes of older versions).

Answer (score 1):

Both Mario 64 and Banjo Kazooie have parts where objects are sliding down towards you, and also have slope dynamics (where you can climb up a certain grade but slide down others). Although there's no literal roof in these games, you can only jump a certain height. I think the frantic nature of some of these levels would really help for the feel of being inside a pinball machine.